# How to use matplotlib backend "TkAgg" in Jupyter

Tags: python, matplotlib, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook

When running the following code in the Jupyter on Ubuntu 20.04:

```
import matplotlib
try:
    matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
except ImportError as e:
    print(e)
    plt = None

assert plt is not None, "matplotlib backend failed"
print("done")
```

Here is the output:

```
Cannot load backend 'TkAgg' which requires the 'tk' interactive framework, as 'headless' is currently running

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_5612/97292621.py in <cell line: 9>()
      7     plt = None
      8 
----> 9 assert plt is not None, "matplotlib backend failed"
     10 print("done")
```

AssertionError: matplotlib backend failed

But I can run it directy from `python3` command line without any problem.

Is there any `python` or `system` package need to be import or install first for running it in Jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running this command on a empty cell:

```
%matplotlib tk
```

Then, execute your plotting commands.

Comment: When running this line in an empty cell, this line will also throw an error: ImportError: Cannot load backend 'TkAgg' which requires the 'tk' interactive framework, as 'headless' is currently running

Comment: have you installed `tk`?

Comment: I think the tk is installed, because when I run the following command in bash python3 command line, it works and the output is "done": import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print("done")

Comment: Is jupyter running in a dedicated environment?

Comment: I don't know what does dedicated environment mean.  but I can run "python3" on bash command line, and then in the "python3" console, I copy & paste the "embedding tk" code, the bash window will popup a chart window: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html

Comment: In jupyer, I run "from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
disp = Display()
disp.start()", and then run the same "embedding tk" on jupyter lab, it just don't show anything.

Comment: Have no more ideas :(